# Writing Blob to storage using PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to write a Blob to storage.  When I construct the Blob like:

```
var blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(json)], { type: 'text/plain' });
```

I get an error in phonegap:

```
TypeError: Illegal contructor
```

this works fine in a desktop Chrome.  I am using PhoneGap 2.9.0 on Android 4.2.1.

What is the proper way to construct a blob?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android WebView prior to KitKat is ancient and lacks quite many features found in modern web browsers. You must try a Blob [polyfill](https://github.com/eligrey/Blob.js).